# Java SNI unrecognized name

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x, sni

I'm on Java 8 using Apache HttpClient (4.5.2) and I get this error:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name`

I know that I could get around that using:

`System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");`

But if I do that other https sites can't be connected to anymore.

From these two sites I can only connect to one depending on whether I enable SNI or not but I have not found a setting that allows me to connect to both succesfully:

- https://www.rainsalestraining.com/
- https://www.multicominc.com/

Can anyone reproduce that or has solved this?

Answer (score 1):

This Exception is raised because the server is returning a certificate which doesn't match the FQDN you requested. Disabling SNI on client-side is not the adequate solution, instead you have to disable the Hostname Verification as explained in the [HttpClient doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e460)

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    sslContext,
    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
```